# Lua write outputs strange byte to file

Tags: windows, lua, bin

When debugging an issue [on writing BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958902/bmp-aspect-ratio-issue/66973982) using binary data with Lua, I ran on a strange issue that some bytes were being introduced.

When we write string.char(10), the bytes 0x0D0A appear.

```
local file = io.open("forbchars.bin","w")

local out = {}
for i=1,255 do
    out[#out+1] = string.char(i)
    out[#out+1] = string.char(255)
end

file:write(table.concat(out))
```

If you inspect this file with Hex editor, you see 0x0D0A bytes instead of 0x0A (10).

How to prevent it? Is this a bug with Lua?

Comment: this is not a bug. this is normal. Lua and many other programming languages translate the newline character `\n`  0x0A to the systems native new line representation. Under Windows that's `\r\n`! read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @Piglet Yes but I regret closing the question because I couldn't find this easily..

Comment: closed questions can still be found. also I find that your question is asked in a way that is very special to your problem and is unlikely to be found by anyone wondering where those carriage returns come from. once you reword your question it's basically a duplicate of existing questions. you should have referred to the Lua reference manual. `io.open` mentions a binary mode. as you're using io.open you should try to understand what that means befor you use io.open. a quick web research reveals that carriage returns will be added under Windows if you don't use that mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binary switch `"wb"` when writing binary data with Lua:

```
local file = io.open("forbchars.bin","wb")
local out = {}
for i=1,255 do
    out[#out+1] = string.char(i)
    out[#out+1] = string.char(255)
end
file:write(table.concat(out))
```